# Disallow user login if email_verified is false

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When a user registers for my application I handle the request through an API and send an email containing a verification link. When the link is clicked it updates the `email_verified` attribute to true. This is working as expected.

The problem I'm having is that a user is allowed to login even when the attribute `email_verified` is set to false.

I'm using amplify to login the user. How can I block user login if the email has not been verified?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to this myself. I was registering the user with a custom lambda function which creates the user using `adminCreateUser`. This API automatically sets the UserStatus to `CONFIRMED` which is the field that is used to determine whether a user can log in or not. I was working on the assumption that it was the `email_verified` field which determined this, which was incorrect.

I fixed this by instead using the `signUp` function of the API which instead creates the user in an `UNCONFIRMED` state and doesn't allow login until the sign up is confirmed.